# I'm confused with the use of 'prevent from' in this sentence

Tags: word-usage

> We can **prevent from** having bad smell by washing our face more often
>   with mild unperfumed or antiseptic soaps and by not eating certain
>   foods such as chips and chocolate.

In this sentence, I'm confused about the use of the verb *'prevent'*. After the word *'prevent'*, should I use the preposition *'from'*?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72619/do-you-prevent-somebody-doing-something-or-prevent-somebody-from-doing-som

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prevent

Comment: Hmm..where did you find this discourse? Since prevent is transitive, a direct object is needed, the sentence should be *"..we can prevent **ourselves** from having.."*

Comment: @user178049 I agree. *Ourselves* is necessary!

Comment: @SovereignSun and *our face* should be subtituted by *our faces*

Comment: @user178049 I assume *our face* is possible, it may mean *a face in general*. Assuming that *our face* is pointing to *each of us* not *us in general*.

Comment: should definitely be "our faces".

Answer (score 1):

*To prevent from* - to stop (someone) from doing something. `[object + from + verb-ing]`

In your case it is:

> We can prevent *(ourselves)* from having bad smell...

Comment: Oh, I am sorry.